# How to make UIStackView fill perfectly equally?

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I am working on a scenario using nested UIStackView instances (a vertical UIStackView containing many one to many horizontal UIStackView instances) to create a grid of equal size cells that can each contain any UIView. This is intended to be a flexible canvas for a variety of games which the user could vary the dimensions of from game to game (e.g. minesweeper, word find, crossword, tile games), so the UIStack view contents are not manually placed in Interface Builder.

A user noted the scenario that given 22 rows of content in the vertical UIStackView and `distribution = .fillEqually`, on iPhone X most of the rows are 33.33 height while two are 33.67. Of course these are not actually equal, but the demo was scaling text to be as big as allowed by the row height and these sizes resulted in text of two different sizes on a screen of supposedly equal size content.

[image: Image of problem]

To create this, I created a new project in Xcode, added a UIStackView in Interface Builder, and implemented the following ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        for _ in 0..<22 {
            let newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 1, height: 10))
            newLabel.font = newLabel.font.withSize(576.0)
            newLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.01
            newLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            newLabel.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
            newLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            newLabel.textAlignment = .center
            newLabel.text = "The quick brown fox..."

            stackView.addArrangedSubview(newLabel)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach({ (view) in
                if let label = view as? UILabel {
                    label.text = "The quick brown fox... \(Double(Int(label.frame.height*100))/100)"
                }
            })
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

What could I do differently to overcome this inequality of height, other than restricting supported devices or row counts, either changing the way the existing UIKit elements are used or supporting the same concept of a dynamic grid of equal-size UIViews through other UIKit classes? My current solution is to use proportional fill, add an empty pad row to the bottom, and tweak its intrinsic size until the intended rows are all equal, and that seems awful.

Thank you!
Mark

Comment: What happens if you stackview top or bottom constraint >= or both and use vertically center. Do all the rows become equal then?

Comment: That's a good idea. I forgot to mention that all four sides of the UIStackView had constraints = 0 to the Safe Area. Switching top and bottom to >= 0 had no effect. It seems to decide first to fill the available space and then figures out how to get the content in there. I tried several combinations of top and bottom, >= and <=, constants, and constraint priorities but only resulted in it looking the same, demonstrating the same problem in a smaller area, and not displaying anything at all. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: this rounding that you are seeing happens sometimes with collection views. The advantage to collection views is that the vertical spacing can be made to compensate the rounding. If I think of something else I will let you know.